# How can I delete specific data in listview using Shared Preference in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I want to remove the item that i choose in listView from sharedPreferences. But I don't know how to include it on my code. I've tried so many codes that I've seen from the internet but it makes my application error.  Can someone give me an idea ?  Big helps. Thanks

This is MySharedPreference class:

```
public class MySharedPreference {
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    // Context
    private Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "pref";
    private static final String SCORES = "scores";

    public MySharedPreference(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void saveHighScoreList(String scoreString) {
        editor.putString(PREF_NAME, scoreString);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getHighScoreList() {
        return pref.getString(PREF_NAME, "");
    }

}
```

And this is my ListViewAdapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter_History extends ArrayAdapter<Input> {

    private Activity activity;

    public ListViewAdapter_History(Activity activity, int resource, List<Input> scores) {
        super(activity, resource, scores);
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Input score = getItem(position);

        holder.score.setText(score.getScore());

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        private TextView score;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.score);
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to execute the delete sharedpreference  to my another class which where the delete button is but I'm still thinking what will I choose the onItemLongClick or a simple delete button.

ps. I hope you understand what I want to achieve. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must instantiate `MySharedPreference` class in your adapter and create a delete method in `MySharedPreference` class :

```
public void deletePrefs(String score){
    editor.remove(score);
}
```

and in your adapter :

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            String s=getItem(position).getScore().getText().toString();
                presfs.deletePrefs(s)
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is presfs ?

Comment: instantiate of ` MySharedPreference` : `MySharedPreference prefs=new MySharedPreference(activity);`